# Cannot yield next inside anonymous function

Tags: node.js, koa

I have a generator function, like this:

```
function *(next) {
  this.redis.get('foo', function(e, r){
    console.log(r)
    yield next;
  })
}
```

I was thinking I could use a co style coding, by using `var r = yield this.redis.get('foo')` but apparently it does not work. The error here is that "next" does not exist anymore inside the anonymous function. How can I access it?

Comment: You have no ; after your console.log

Comment: that's not the problem. semicolons are not mandatory in js

Comment: I would not miss them if I were you. I would write elegant code. And when someone point out that my code is not elegant, I would thank him.

Comment: LOL! .......  ^ Above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yield` keyword only in generators. To handle your problem you should make `this.redis.get` return a promise instead of accepting a callback. To do this, write a `promisify` function which converts a function expecting a callback into one that returns a promise:

```
function promisify(method) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            method.apply(null, args.concat(function(e, r) {
                e ? reject(e) : resolve(r);
            }));
        });
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
function *(next) {
    var r = yield promisify(this.redis.get)('foo');
    yield next;
}
```

Alternatively, some Promise libraries provide a `promisify` function. For example [bluebird's Promise.promisify](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyfunction-nodefunction--dynamic-receiver---function) can be used like this:

```
var Promise = require( 'bluebird' );
function *(next){
    var redisGet = Promise.promisify( this.redis.get );
    yield redisGet( 'foo' );
    yield next;
}
```

Comment: In the Bluebird example `redisGet` should be promisified during startup and be cached for later use.

Comment: @GabrielTomitsuka Yes, it always much better to do `promifisy` outside of the function. But in the question  `redis` is property of `this`. I cannot get `this` outside of the function.